# Set absolute path for root directory in HTML on local filesystem

Tags: html, linux, web, absolute-path

How can I use absolute paths in my website while testing on my local filesystem? I know that I can use `/` to access the root directory of my website. However, this works only when my website is on the server. I want to be able to use absolute paths on my local filesystem so that I can do proper testing before uploading.

Is there a way to set a variable to a root directory in HTML? Something similar to Linux where you can define a variable `WEBPATH=/home/user/website`. Thus I can use e.g `src="WEBPATH/folder/file.html` for all the files I use in my website and I can modify `WEBPATH` depending on whether I am testing locally or using the server root folder.

I am open to other workarounds as well.

Comment: maybe interesting? [A PHP bootstrapping crash course (Application Startup)](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/146). I develop on windows and host on linux. I do not have  to change much. Actually, Once I get the `bootstrap` file correct - I just copy the code to 'live'. I don't use a framework - I learn from them and use the components.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't started with PHP yet but this will definitely be of use!

Comment: sorry - didn't read the instructions as well as I should have. ;-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a file url to access your HTML in the browser, in which case an easy way to get absolute paths working is by using a local webserver to serve your site.

If you have Python 3 installed, you can run `python3 -m http.server` from the command line at your web root, and it will serve your site at `localhost:8000`.

Comment: At least since Python 3.5 the command to run is `python -m http.server`