# Unable to find images and animations when opened index.html file from root directory

Tags: html, css

I have designed a webpage in visual studio code(IDE). When I open the file(index.html) from VS code(IDE) every image is visible normally, but when I open the same file(index.html) from root directory, I'm unable to see my and images. Why is this happening. I have checked every link and it is correct.

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-icon">
       <img src="/Travelly/images/flight.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <h4>Fly</h4>
    <p>Flight included in every purchase.</p>
</div>
```

This is a part of code in which I have my image file in location-Travelly/images.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code to show what is not working. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello, this may be because you have used relative path as the image src and sometimes it will break. Open the page and see the source of the page what is the path of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using an absolute path: `/Travelly/images/flight.jpg`

If you open the .html file directly from your computer, then that absolute path with look at the root of your computer (the first `/` in the path), not the root of your website.

You have two options here:

1. Make the paths in the HTML relative by ommitting the `/` at the front; this may require you to use `..`
2. [Run a local server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32260835/1406083)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful

Comment: @NaeemShaik if one of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open .html page in the browser.
2.Open the Dev tools (usually by F12).
3.See if '404 resource not find' error is displayed.

If there is, make sure you fix proper path to a file.
Study the differences between absolute and relative paths.